# Is there any expression like "minor fun"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, vocabulary

"Minor fun" or "trivial fun", which I think means that tiny, little, minor, trivial things or actions that is funny or interesting.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: If intent is involved, it's _light humour_.

Comment: A _distraction_?

Answer (score 1):

*Entertainment* is a possibility.

**Watching 'epic fail' videos was their favorite form of entertainment.**

"Entertainment" runs the gamut from the trivial to the enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

Amusing, comical, humorous, lighthearted, jocular, witty, mirthful, droll, diverting.